# Help identifying a cyberpunk novel from the early 90s?

Tags: story-identification, cyberpunk

I'd really REALLY like to dig up a book I read years back when I was getting through a lot of cyberpunk in the early 90s. 
What I can remember: 
The main character was a japanese guy, I think called Yoshi who could speed up his nervous system to aid combat. 
There were also "enemy" characters called "blades of God". 
Vague memory and possibly confusing with other novels here but I think a Triumph Boneville featured in there (?!) and towards the end of the story there was an orbiting spacecraft called "Zion". 
Any ideas?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This sounds like [Dreams of Gods and Men](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dreams-Gods-Men-W-T-Quick/dp/0708883303) by W. T. Quick. The character is Toshi not Yoshi. For example this mention of the Blades of God:

> Toshi stared at a tiny figure picking its dainty way through the rubble of the God's retreat, moving slowly toward the fifty-meter wall of rock which sheltered Toshi's hideaway. He knew that form. Blades of God, they called themselves. He squinted at the little yellow killer, trying to estimate how much time he had left. Not much, probably. Those fragile-looking samurai were unbelievably effective at search and destroy.

Toshi has implants that allow him to be remote controlled, and this allows speeded up reactions:

> The implants which connected him to Levin were modeled on some very nasty wrinkles in mind control the NASA-INTEL people dreamed up in the late nineties and later discarded as too dangerous for even their arcane purposes. Levin actually used him as a remote input-output unit. He watched from Toshi's eyes; heard from his ears, shared his enthusiasm for the taste of dark beer and the smell of fresh bread. In their strange relationship, Toshi functioned at times as an ultimate Waldo. Berg said it was safe. Toshi trusted Berg. And Berg had designed Levin. But, he thought uncomfortably, we've never truly put it to the test -- and when the Blade flowed into his rocky nest like a striking bushmaster, all his emotions clamored blindly against the prison of his skull. Toshi's hands, covered with electrified, razor-studded mandrakes, moved suddenly, a blur faster than he could follow. The unbidden movement shocked him.
>
> Amazing, Toshi thought. Nice set of reflexes.

And finally there is the motorbike:

> Closer. He rubbed his eyes and watched the cloud of steam forming above his lips. He rummaged cloudy memories. Motorcycle, an old one. He closed his eyes and tried to concentrate. Triumph. Bonneville 650. One of the best of the antiques, a road-burner from the dawn of time.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this sounds like a miss-remembered Neuromancer to me, although chances are there are other books with the same framework. The mention of the space station named Zion and nervous system rang alarm bells. The main character in Neuromancer is called Case, and he gets poisoned with a neurotoxin which cripples his nervous system and he can no longer hack. He goes black market and gets implanted with super-fast nervous system but also the same toxin that crippled him in the first place, with it not being triggered provided he gets the job done quickly.

[Official Gibson page (with chapter one excerpt)](http://www.williamgibsonbooks.com/books/neuromancer.asp)

Comment: I believe that Yoshi was a genetically enhanced body guard for the house of Tesser and was assigned the mission of protecting the house when Case and Molly did their cyber/physical raid.

Comment: Hmm I don't recall from Neuromancer, may very well have been in one of the other books though in the trilogy though

Comment: The bodyguard was named "Hideo".

Comment: Hideo! That's the name. Thanks Bharat.